# Subtracting movement between units over time

Tags: r, dplyr, subtraction

Here is my query as I haven't been able to find a suitable answer yet..
I have a dataset which describes all combinations of total number of people moving between different danish municipalities over a 13 year span.

What I would like to have is the sum of movement between all combinations of municipalities over the year span.

See code below:

```
library("tidyverse")
library("statsDK")


# GETTING DATA FROM DANISH ARCHIVES
fly66_0 <- retrieve_data("FLY66", ALDER = "0")
fly66_1 <- retrieve_data("FLY66", ALDER = "1")
fly66_2 <- retrieve_data("FLY66", ALDER = "2")
fly66_3 <- retrieve_data("FLY66", ALDER = "3")
fly66_4 <- retrieve_data("FLY66", ALDER = "4")
fly66_5 <- retrieve_data("FLY66", ALDER = "5")

fly_66 <- rbind(fly66_0, fly66_1, fly66_2, fly66_3, fly66_4, fly66_5)

fly_66 <- fly_66 %>%
  group_by(TO_muni, FROM_muni, YEAR) %>%
  summarise(Number = sum(Number))
```

This results in the following table (I've changed the column names to english):

```
# A tibble: 6 x 4
# Groups:   TILKOMMUNE, FRAKOMMUNE [3]
  TO_muni    FROM_muni    YEAR    Number
  <chr>       <chr>      <dbl>   <dbl>
1 101         202       2006       1
2 101         202       2007       3
3 202         101       2006       2
4 202         101       2007       3
5 101         303       2006       2
6 303         101       2007       1
```

But what I would like is something like:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 4
# Groups:   TILKOMMUNE, FRAKOMMUNE [3]
  TO_muni    FROM_muni    YEAR    Number
  <chr>       <chr>      <dbl>   <dbl>
1 101         202       2006      -1
2 101         202       2007       0
3 202         101       2006       1
4 202         101       2007       0
5 101         303       2006       2
6 303         101       2006      -2
5 101         303       2007      -1
6 303         101       2007       1
```

I've tried the following, but i couldn't make much sense of it:

```
library("reshape2")
fly_66 <- fly_66 %>% 
  dcast(TO_muni + YEAR ~ FROM_muni, value.var = "YEAR", fill = 0)
```

Hope it makes sense and thanks in advance.

Comment: No need to use reshape, just summarise using dplyr group function.

Comment: I can't get your `statsDK` library but I think this should be easy to solve. You can make a copy of your data set and reverse the names of `TO_muni` and `FROM_muni`. Then `full_join` the original and copy, and finally use `mutate` to compute the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Not straightforward, but you could do it in 3 steps

Starting from:
`fly_66 <- rbind(fly66_0, fly66_1, fly66_2, fly66_3, fly66_4, fly66_5)`

You first get your actual output:

```
fly_66a <- fly_66 %>%
  group_by(TO_muni, FROM_muni, YEAR) %>%
  summarise(Number = sum(Number))
```

Then you "negate" it for the opposite flow:

```
fly_66b <- fly_66 %>%
  group_by(TO_muni, FROM_muni, YEAR) %>%
  summarise(Number = -sum(Number)) %>% #negative sum here
  rename(FROM_muni = TO_muni, TO_muni = FROM_muni) #you invert the column names to simulate the opposite flow
```

You can now bind it, and use the "complete" function to generate the missing combination, which you can simply fill with 0s

```
fly_66_final <- fly_66a %>%
  bind_rows(fly_66b) %>%
  complete(TO_muni, FROM_muni, YEAR, fill = list(Number = 0))
```

You can then arrange the way you want